# How to remove black patches under hair?

Tags: hair, error

[image]

for some reason, whenever i use blender cycles the hair get weird back spots under it? anyway to make the black spots disappear or transparent?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the hair strands that are on top of other hair strands are shadowing the ones underneath. Try adding more light bounces for transparency (In the Render properties tab, Light paths, Max bounces)